# DateTimePicker is not working when VF API version is 30.0 or higher

Tags: visualforce, api, date-picker

In our Visualforce page we need a date picker which must bind to some local variable in our controller(not sObject variable).

So we used the following code

```
<apex:inputText id="selected_date" onclick="DatePicker.pickDate(true, this, false);"  
                                    value="{!selectedDate}" size="10" style="width:70px;"/>
```

But when I click the input box it shows 2 javascript errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of null
```

After googled the error I got [**this**](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XU5AAM) link. This link suggest the workaround as change the VF API version to 29.0 or lower.

This seems temporary solution. Why they removed this option in newer APIs ? Is there any better solution available  ?

Comment: Can you try this.. I think you need to specify size="10"  `<apex:inputText id="selected_date" onclick="DatePicker.pickDate(true, this, false);"  value="{!selectedDate}" size="10"/>`

Comment: @Ratan I tried that also

Comment: So if you change your page API to 29 or lower then It work or not? If this work then report this issue

Comment: @Ratan after change API to 29 it is working. But it is not a proper solution right.

Comment: SANN3 If this is the case then report this issue to salesforce. This is not code issue.. and wait for other response may be they have any solution..

Comment: @SANN3 SFSupport in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/asksalesforce/status/707213739053989889) has requested that you log a case on this for investigation. Please let us know if you have any issues getting it filed. Reference that tweet if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dummy sObject and added a date field and used in my VF page. It is working without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to make sure if you are using classic date picker is, don't set `StandardStyleSheet="false"` in the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because salesforce is not loading the required js file for displaying the date picker. You can avoid this issue by adding a dummy date field (hide it using display: none;) in the visualforce page so that Salesforce will load all the required js files for displaying the default date picker.

Update code will be like this

```
<apex:inputText id="selected_date" onclick="DatePicker.pickDate(true, this, false);"  
                value="{!selectedDate}" size="10" style="width:70px;"/>

<div style="display:none;">
    <apex:inputField value="anyObject.AnyDateField__c" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is change the tag from apex:inputText to apex:input with `type="date"`

**Before:**

```
<apex:inputText id="selected_date" onclick="DatePicker.pickDate(true, this, false);" value="{!selectedDate}" size="10" style="width:70px;"/>
```

**After:**

```
<apex:input type="date" id="selected_date" value="{!selectedDate}" size="10" />
```

Reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kGxpIAE

Answer (score -1):

`type="text"` and `showDatePicker="false"`attributes helped in my case.